# get NullPointerException in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, sdk, android-viewpager

```
public class News extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private ListView listView;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment,container,false);
        listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser){
            if (isVisibleToUser) getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.homeMenuItems)[4]);
            MyCreate();
        }
    }

    public void MyCreate(){
        listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 6;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView==null){
                    convertView=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.news_adapter,null);
                }
                return convertView;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you start it, you get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.EraNewGames.Elbase.homeFragments.News.setUserVisibleHint(News.java:38)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1103)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:513)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:505)
    at com.EraNewGames.Elbase.HomeActivity$2.onItemClick(HomeActivity.java:92)
```

I realized how out of this error, the problem misrepresented that lost link to listView. 
But what then ... Not only I have to use Fragments Yes, so not to create fragments of the left and right , as every piece is a method that uses the Internet . 
And this is the extra traffic. 
To this was not, I decided to check if the window is active then use it .

Why does the `ListView` get `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setUserVisibleHint() is called before onCreateView(), therefore the list view is not initialised.

Comment: what about me then ? cause onCreateView  in setUserVisibleHint()?

Comment: You have to put more effort when writing a sentence. I do not know what "cause onCreateView  in setUserVisibleHint()?"  means.